# New answers to ancient questions

Tags: discussion, answers, old-questions

About 10 years ago I was a beginner and asked many questions in SO. Lately, I noticed there are some new accounts that dig out my relatively "high view count" questions and post a somehow legit answer to them.

I would assume these are people who want to get some score for themselves?

I am not sure what my point is here :) but I somehow get annoyed to see the "notification" and then check it, it brings back bitter memories from past :))

Does someone have the same feeling about this? is this encouraged or discouraged according to SO rules?

Comment: There is nothing inherently bad about it, but there is even a review queue to check of what's being posted is actually any good. I present you [Late Answers Review Queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148088/why-are-late-answers-reviewed).

Comment: Tends to be "oh, I know the answer too" posts.  Workarounds are to click "protect" on the question (like I just did with your recently active question) and to configure the email preferences in your profile to cut down on the emails (select "No").